# Node-Red/ conversation service

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, node-red, watson-conversation

Can anyone provide me with instructional process on how to implement conversation, text to speech and speech to text service together in a single app? Can I do it at Node-Red? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a pretty good Node-RED flow (with documentation)that you can follow here - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-labs/tree/master/starter-kits/ok_watson

It uses a microphone, STT, Tone-Analyser, Conversation, TTS, speaker. If you don't have the nodes then there is a list of extra npm modules that you might need to add here - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-labs/tree/master/starter-kits

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried to get microphone and speaker node using the npm command, but it does not seem to help.

Comment: How you add the microphone and speaker node depends on where you are running from. How is actually documented in the second link I posted. - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-labs/tree/master/starter-kits. There is a link to video instructions on that page.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. So do i directly copy these: "node-red-contrib-browser-utils":"0.x",
    "node-red-contrib-media-utils":"0.x",
    "node-red-contrib-play-audio": "2.0.x",
    "node-red-dashboard": "2.0.x", onto my package.json?

Comment: Yes, and then redeploy your instance of node-RED to fetch the additional nodes.